# Select XML tags which have a specific text in it with REGEX

Tags: xml, regex

i am currently working on a regex to select nodes that have "Roger" as a name.

Ex.

```
<Person>
 <Age>10</Age>
 <Name>Roger</Name>
</Person>

<Person>
 <Age>15</Age>
 <Name>Amelia</Name>
</Person>

<Person>
 <Age>45</Age>
 <Name>Roger</Name>
</Person>
```

Currently im trying 
\s*[\s\S.]*Roger[\s\S.]

but everything gets selected and i can't figure out a way to ignore amelia

Comment: Which language are you using ?

Comment: The interesting thing about XML is that it's not a [regular langauge](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regular_language), which means it's impossible to parse (in the general case) with regular expressions. While you can probably make a regex work for this problem, you should consider using a dedicated XML parser.

Comment: I'm trying to add a REGEX rule from the Beyond Compare 2 application, a file comparison tool

Comment: Do all records look like this, or might <age> and <name> be in a different order, have other tags between/around them, or have attributes?

Comment: This was just an example, a lot of tag can appear randomly between <person> tags, There are cases where I can get up to 50 additional tags. Order may vary. There are also attributes for every tag

Answer (score 0):

This should help you:

```
<Person>\s+<Age>\d+</Age>\s+<Name>Roger</Name>\s+</Person>
```